# Why do I lose indexes and column header information on using np.hstack when concatenating two df in python?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes:
Reprex:

DF1

```
X
Yes
No
Maybe
```

DF2

```
Y
Yes
No
Maybe

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
train = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([DF1,DF2]))
```

train

```
0 1
Yes Yes
No  No
Maybe Maybe
```

Why do my headers change from X and Y. the train df should keep my original headers from both df. I tried making axis=1 and headers=true but it did not work. pd.concat is not effective because i end up with more rows than what are in my original df.

I also tried

```
df.reset_index()
```

but even after that pd.concat gave me more rows than my original two dataframes have.

Comment: `pandas` allows dataframes to be hstacked by `numpy`, `numpy` does not care about the headers.  There is no reason `numpy` would keep the headers.

Comment: What is the best fix? within the function?

Comment: you should use `pd.concat` instead.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`. If you have different indexes you can use something like this `pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)`

Comment: this is reprex. pd.concat is increasing my number of rows and is not recommended

Comment: `pd.concat(axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: train = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([DF1,DF2]), columns = ['X', 'Y'])

Comment: @Jorge thanks.so there is no way to retain headers. We have to add them each time in the function?

Comment: if you want, you can do the concat method.. few comments before mine. (pd.concat([DF1, DF2], 1))

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that *Numpy* methods operate not on DataFrames,
but on underlying *Numpy* arrays, **without** any index or
column data (indices of rows and columns names).

To check this, run: `np.hstack([DF1, DF2])` and you will get:

```
array([['Yes', 'Yes'],
       ['No', 'No'],
       ['Maybe', 'Maybe']], dtype=object)
```

To keep column names, use e.g.:

```
pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis=1)
```

This time the result will be:

```
       X      Y
0    Yes    Yes
1     No     No
2  Maybe  Maybe
```